# Why am I getting permission denied on an ownership change?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, amazon-rds, postgresql-9.4, owner

My current user is `pronto`

```
mediapop_staging=> select current_user;
 current_user
--------------
 pronto
(1 row)
```

This user a standard super user created on AWS RDS.

```
mediapop_staging=> \du pronto
                        List of roles
 Role name |          Attributes           |    Member of
-----------+-------------------------------+-----------------
 pronto    | Create role, Create DB       +| {rds_superuser}
           | Password valid until infinity |
```

But I'm getting this:

```
mediapop_staging=> REASSIGN OWNED BY pronto TO mediapop_staging;
ERROR:  permission denied to reassign objects
```

Why? How can I resolve it?

Comment: `rds_superuser` is not the same thing as a PostgreSQL superuser.  This is fundamentally a RDS question, not a plain PostgreSQL question, so you should tag it appropriately.  People who only know the community version of PostgreSQL probably can't help you.

Comment: It worked for me. https://sysadmintips.com/services/databases/postgresql-error-permission-denied-to-reassign-objects/

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to @Spike for comment, for solution which worked for me ([source](https://sysadmintips.com/services/databases/postgresql-error-permission-denied-to-reassign-objects/))

This assumes that objects are reassigned from role `admin` to role `new_admin`.

1.Create a new role:

```
mydb=> CREATE ROLE change_owner LOGIN;
CREATE ROLE
```

2.Make both the old owner and the new owner roles members of the newly created role:

```
mydb=> GRANT admin TO change_owner;
GRANT ROLE
mydb=> GRANT new_admin TO change_owner;
GRANT ROLE
```

3.Logout from psql and login using the new role:

```
$ psql -U change_owner mydb
mydb=>
```

4.Execute the reassignment:

```
mydb=> REASSIGN OWNED BY admin TO new_admin
REASSIGN OWNED
```

Comment: Nice.  Was necessary to specify a password for the role; e.g. _ALTER ROLE change_owner WITH PASSWORD 'change';_  Applied to RDS 10.14 serverless.

Comment: BTW, the solution solved the dilemma of transferring ownership where the login account is also the owner.

Answer (score 2):

A variation of the [great answer by @OtoShavadze](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/302042/153302):

```
mydb=> GRANT admin TO <current_user>;
GRANT ROLE
mydb=> GRANT new_admin TO <current_user>;
GRANT ROLE
mydb=> REASSIGN OWNED BY admin TO new_admin;
REASSIGN OWNED
```

This removes the need to logout and back in as a different role.

Then you can clean up with:

```
mydb=> REVOKE admin FROM <current_user>;
REVOKE ROLE
mydb=> REVOKE new_admin FROM <current_user>;
REVOKE ROLE
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some unintuitive permissions requirements when using `REASSIGN` without a superuser.  See this other [post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62557497/79079) where I answered the same question.

Comment: I get this error even while logged in as the postgres superuser...

Comment: @Cerin the most likely explanation to this is, that you are using Postgres on a Cloud provider, for example AWS RDS. They do not grant the actual "superuser" privileges to the users they create, but instead, a trimmed down "rds_superuser" role that can do most, but not all of the actual Postgres "superuser".

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to run [REASSIGN OWNED](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-reassign-owned.html) and [DROP OWNED](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-drop-owned.html). The 1st way is with a superuser and the 2nd way is with a normal user.

### <The 1st way>:

For example, first, log in to `apple` database with any superuser e.g., `postgres`. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57975093/create-a-superuser-in-postgres/77260939#77260939) explains how to create a superuser. and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757431/postgres-upgrade-a-user-to-be-a-superuser/77274571#77274571) explains how to make a user a superuser:

```
psql -U postgres apple
```

Finally, you can run `REASSIGN OWNED` and `DROP OWNED` as shown below:

```
REASSIGN OWNED BY david TO peter
```

Or:

```
REASSIGN OWNED BY peter TO david
```

Or:

```
DROP OWNED BY david;
```

Or:

```
DROP OWNED BY peter;
```

### <The 2nd way>:

For example, first, log in to any database e.g., `postgres` database with any superuser e.g., `postgres` as shown below:

```
psql -U postgres
```

Then, create the user `john` as shown below:

```
CREATE ROLE john WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'banana';
```

Then, grant the users `david` and `peter` to the user `john`, exit as shown below:

```
GRANT david TO john;
GRANT peter TO john;
\q
```

Then, log in to `apple` database with the user `john` as shown below:

```
psql -U john apple
```

Finally, you can run `REASSIGN OWNED` and `DROP OWNED` as shown below:

```
REASSIGN OWNED BY david TO peter
```

Or:

```
REASSIGN OWNED BY peter TO david
```

Or:

```
DROP OWNED BY david;
```

Or:

```
DROP OWNED BY peter;
```